# Excel to DataTable (Missing data when imported)

Tags: excel, vb.net, odbc

I've made a programm that import `excel` files into `MySQL DataBase` till now that was working perfectly as all excel files had the same structure but now i have to import files that could or couldn't have data in some cells and it seems to be a problem to `ODBC` while importing excel file in `DataTable`

Actually if in Excel file there are two rows

```
ID NAME CODE CODE2
1  ABDC 123 
2  ABBC 1234 11111
```

When i import that in DataTable via ODBC it will become

```
ID NAME CODE CODE2
1  ABDC 123 
2  ABBC 1234
```

Seems like that if there are some columns with some empty cells it will import the whole column as empty, so the question is how can i import all cells empty or not?

Here is the method i use to import excel file to datatable

```
    Dim constring As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & strFileName & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=NO;IMEX=1"""
    Dim con As New OleDbConnection(constring & "")

    con.Open()

    Dim myTableName = con.GetSchema("Tables").Rows(0)("TABLE_NAME")


    Dim sqlquery As String = String.Format("SELECT * FROM [{0}]", myTableName)
    Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(sqlquery, con)
    da.Fill(dt)
```

Here is a screen which show the DataTable and Excel file i'm trying to import.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried specifying a range (a generic range can work ,too), as in `SELECT * FROM [sheet1$A0:ZZ]`. Or more specific, as in `[sheet1$A0:E65535]`

Comment: Perhaps this articel might shed some light on your problem: https://www.sourcecodester.com/tutorials/visual-basic-net/13043/how-import-excel-file-mysql-database-using-vbnet.html